# How to configure Kafka Streams/Kafka for intermittent event flow with long gaps between events?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am building a product using kafka and Kafka streams with Java/Python.

The product is to process data from several disparate external data sources which include both real time and hourly batched events. There could be long gaps, hours together when no events will arrive from the external sources. Some of these events from different sources needs to be correlated and aggregated for which I plan to use Kafka Streams.

Given that the use cases most often exemplified for Kafka/Kafka streams are high volume, high throughput fast flowing realtime events, I'm concerned as to whether my use case fits here. So to that end, my question is:

- given the intermittent nature of the event flow and the long gaps,
  what are some of the configuration settings that I need to look into
  so that connections don't timeout and no rebalances occur.
- Are there any gotchas that will bite me if I proceed down this
  architecture ?

Comment: If you have really long time period discrepancies between your various input sources, then the Processor API of Kafka Streams may be a good option. See for example the `CustomStreamTableJoin` at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, but I'll try to give your some hints.
It is not specified if the topology would be stateful or stateless.

I will assume Kafka as the underlying storage is a given here.

- If you're mixing real-time and batch, and plan to perform joins between them, you will have to define window times on those streams (see [Windows](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Windows.html), [JoinWindows](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html)).
- You will have to ensure the minimum times so consumer offsets do not expire. IIRC, newer versions default at 7 days, but previous versions had shorter times. See [KIP-186](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-186%3A+Increase+offsets+retention+default+to+7+days)
- If on cloud, look for burstable options (if you overflow your rate, you'll have problems!). Also, make sure your brokers can handle it, and probably will benefit from increasing Zookeeper session timeouts.
- Ensure topic retention is configured for your max possible retention times. A topic would have to keep its info until the max possible waiting time for info that may join with it from another topic.

In principle, and without more information, I can't see why it wouldn't work for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the response. To clarify - The topology is stateful, the stream processing is part of a microservice that relies on stateful streams to performs joins. Some downstream services (python based) are stateless but in those cases since streams are not supported anyway, using plain Kafka topics for messaging. To your second point, you are right that the current version defaults to 7 days.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using Kafka Streams via Jython?  A few companies are doing this.